# Antivirus preventing exe file from being extracted?

Tags: ruby, exe, antivirus, devkit

I want to extract the devkit for ruby. Its a 7zip archive but one file "mv.exe" is not being extracted and it wont run as well even if I rename it in the archive,extract and rename it back to "mv.exe".

Is it my Mcafee security/antivirus or some other OS config?.

It worked on my home pc but the office pc is giving me this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a false positive. You can add an exception in this case if the antivirus has this option. If not, you can disable the antivirus while extracting and afterwards re-enable it.